# Placing Skulls/Heads Inside Glass Blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On the server [MCMagic](http://mcmagic.us), I found a head inside a glass block at the Japan pavilion (`/warp japan`) in Epcot. Because this was the first time I have come across that, I have no idea how it was done.

In singleplayer, I tried using a piston to shove a head inside a glass block, but the head kept dropping itself. Then, I tried placing more glass blocks around the first one to prevent the head from popping out, but it still did after I activated the piston. How do I keep a head inside a glass block?

[image: A player’s head inside a glass block]

Comment: ughh, try mcedit

Comment: @ardaozkal Using that, I tried nudging the block inside glass, but it didn’t work. Only the head remained when I opened the world in-game again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Player skulls and glass are both blocks, and only one block can occupy the same space.

What you can do is summon an invisible armor stand (which is an entity, not a block) wearing a player skull into the glass block:

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~1 ~ {Invisible:1b,Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:"minecraft:skull",Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:"Skylinerw"}}]}
```

Comment: Oh cool. Thank you! Then this is very likely the way the builder pulled off this trick. I can also use flat snow blocks underneath the bottom full block to adjust the armor stand’s Y position.